# Java 8 import cannot be resolved when executing with CircleCI

Tags: java, maven, circleci

I have a Java 8 project, built with maven. I'm using CircleCI as continuous integration, and I get the following error message during the build:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import java.util.function cannot be resolved
```

I have:

```
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
```

in my maven-compiler plugin. When I run the build locally, with `mvn clean install`, or with `mvn integration-test`, as it is executed in CircleCI, I get no errors.

Is there some problem when using CircleCI with a Java 8 project?

The project source can be found here: https://github.com/verjigorm/DragonPunch.git

Edit:
I had a look at the links suggested below, and fixed the build by adding:

```
machine:
  java:
    version:
      oraclejdk8
```

to my circle.yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you specify that you want to use Java 8 in your pom file does not mean it's going to be available.

According to the [Circle Documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/language-java), they default to `oraclejdk7` as the Java runtime. You'll have to specify something that supports Java 8, like `oraclejdk8` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CircleCi documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/language-java), it uses by default Java 1.7.0_55

Check the configuration to set a JDK 8 instead of this